# Nonce generation with DateTime Tick count

Tags: c#, nonce

In our web app, we use an external service for a certain feature. To request that external service, we have to add a `key` in request header which is an integer and unique to all my request, technically call `nonce`

for nonce generation i used

```
var nonce = (long) DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).Ticks*100 + random.Next(100);
```

Now, in 100 concurrent requests, the key is being duplicated. How the key is being duplicated?

I can't use GUID because I need ever increasing integer value.

Comment: Time is not a good source of entropy for nonces. Why don't you use [GUIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: If you have truly concurrent requests then `DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).Ticks*100` is a constant for those requests. Then you've only got `random.Next(100)` left. It doesn't take much to get a collision then. A trivial (but not ideal) option would be to just simply do `random.Next()`.

Comment: @ArthurAttout I need ever increasing integer value.

Comment: Why do you need it to be increasing ? Based on your requirements (and on the natural signification of the word **Nonce**) the number only needs to be unique. GUIDs will be very useful for that (they will not be unique, but you have an extremely, extremely low probability to have a collision)

Comment: (btw your initial code doesn't guarantee your number to be ever-increasing either)

Comment: @ArthurAttout I guess it is ever increasing.

Comment: It's been always increasing because it's highly probable it will be, but it is not **guaranteed**. If you have a concurrent request (like @Enigmativity suggested), then all you have is a constant + `nextInt(100)`. If the generator yields 50 then 5, your new number is less than your previous.

Comment: @ArthurAttout Yes now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have truly concurrent requests then `DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).Ticks * 100` is a constant for those requests. Then you've only got `random.Next(100)` left and that doesn't take much to get a collision then. A trivial (but not ideal) option would be to just simply do `random.Next()`.

A better idea would be this:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static Random __random = new Random();
private static int shift = 32;
private static long counter = 0L;

public long GenerateNextNonce()
{
    var major = ++counter << shift;
    var minor = (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks ^ __random.Next()) & (1L << shift - 1);
    return major + minor;
}
```

The `++counter` ensures that you have a increasing sequence of numbers - alone this would be sufficient in producing a nonce, but it is highly predictable so would be open to hacking.

Computing `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks ^ __random.Next()` ensures a fairly random number that is not purely dependent on the implementation of `Random` so it ensures that this number is highly **unpredictable**, but it is not necessarily increasing.

The use of the `shift` value ensures that the `counter` value is shifted to the "high-end" or major part of the number. Calling `(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks ^ __random.Next()) & (1L << shift - 1)` truncates the high end bits of the random part of the nonce ensuring that the minor value doesn't share any bits with the major number.

I ran this with a `shift` value of `32` and produced `100_000_000` values and only exhausted less than 5% of the available numbers heading towards `long.MaxValue`. As long as you produce less than 2 billion nonces you should be good. If you want more then reduce `shift`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is because of `random.Next(100)`.

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2), random.Next returns a non-negative value which is less than 100.
After 100 concurrent request, same value may be getting returned by this method.

As suggested in above comments, you should go for GUIDs as there is an extremely low chance that they'll be the same.

Or else if you do not want GUIDs, then you can try below code (taken from this [blog](http://mylifeismymessage.net/getnonce-a-c-routine-to-generate-the-nonce-code-for-ws-security/)).

It should help you to resolve the issue.

```
public static string GetNonce()
{
    // better to get unique random number if 
    // called mulitple times
    Random r = RandomProvider.GetThreadRandom(); 

    DateTime created = DateTime.Now;

    string nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SHA1Encrypt(created + r.Next().ToString())));

    return nonce;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "GUIDs as they will always be unique" - well, the best you could say is that there is an extremely low chance that they'll be the same.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity ! I was thinking of the same while typing the answer.  But avoided that initially as i was not sure if that detail was required in context of question.  But anyway, I have added that in the answer now.

Comment: @Moshii - did you try the GetNonce method from the answer ?  Is it working for the concurrency level your program expects ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari As I said from my web app I do http request to another service and the api only accepts integer value.

Comment: @Moshii - can you mention what is the scope of 'random' variable ?  Is it created everytime you want to generate nonce, it is same application wide ?